# How to use lambda expression with asp.net DataList in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I have created a DataList on aspx file that contains checkbox control that repeated base on a data pulled from database.

I want to get DataList items and work on it, I already did use `foreach` loop, but I want to select and filter the items using lambda.

I couldn't convert the `DataList.items` to List nor an Array. there is `DataList.items.CopyTo` but it copies to Array object and couldn't convert to `DataListItem []` array.

this is what has been done:

```
int count = 0;

foreach (DataListItem item in weaknesses.Items)
{
    CheckBox weakness = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cbWeakness");
    if (weakness.Checked)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

and this is what I'm trying to do:

```
count = weaknesses.Items.Where(i => ((CheckBox)i.FindControl("cbWeakness")).checked).Count();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with this lambda.

```
int count = DataList1.Items.Cast<DataListItem>().Where(x => ((CheckBox)x.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked).Count();
```

The DataList

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```